# Heroku: Two-Factor Authentication: Your identity couldn't be verified

Tags: macos, authentication, heroku, two-factor-authentication

Got stuck at - Heroku: Two-Factor Authentication: Your identity couldn't be verified. please let me know how can access my account or bypass the 2FA. I'm not logged in any other devices.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: "Found no credentials on this device" while trying to login in safari.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? having the same issue?